# Install basic GNOME without any app

Tags: gnome, dependencies, evolution, evince, gnome-calculator

I am trying to remove Evolution from my system.
However, removing it also removes the GNOME environment.

So, I conclude that it is impossible to have GNOME without Evolution.
Please note I am NOT interested in hiding it!

According to my understanding one should not be able to have Evolution without GNOME or KDE or some other desktop environment.

What kind of nonsense is this setup to force Evolution down the throat of the users? This behavior seems much more applicable for Windows.

This is not the only strange dependency.
Other that follow similar pattern:
gnome-calculator, gnome-contacts, evince

Finally, the question:
Is it somehow possible to install GNOME desktop environment and have only:
File Manager and Terminal

Comment: What do you mean by "removing it also removes the GNOME environment"? Which other packages are also getting removed? Please [edit] your question and clarify. If it's the `gnome-desktop` or a similar *metapackage*, then most probably *for all intents and purposes* it won't be an issue.

Comment: apt purge evolution
among other packages removes: gnome-core

Comment: Be careful as you appear to be mixing up the `evolution` MUA (mail user agent) application with `evolution-data-server` (https://developer.gnome.org/eds/stable/) which is a very different thing (and a necessary part of gnome)

Comment: Not really, I have in mind exactly evolution and not the data-server package.

Comment: Why do you *need* `gnome-core`? It's not even installed by default in a standard Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only evolution-data-server is a dependency of the Gnome Desktop. You can run Gnome Shell without having Evolution.

To install only core Gnome Shell components in Ubuntu, install `gnome-session`.

```
sudo apt install gnome-session
```

Once installed, you will be able to select either "Gnome Shell", a session that runs on Wayland, or "Gnome Shell on xorg". The latter runs on the traditional X server, as does the default Ubuntu desktop, which uses a customized Gnome Shell.

Comment: I think this might have helped.
After removing the packages I don't need from the default installation and subsequently running apt autoremove, I was getting only terminal and no GUI.
Re-installing gnome-core would return the evolution.
Maybe gnome-session was marked as auto installed in the default install and was removed by autoremove. Need to repeat this to be certain.

Comment: It depends on how you initially installed Gnome. Not sure if  on your system `gnome-session` was installed at all.

Comment: I think it would be good to mark the gnome-session as manually installed during default installation. Then it will not be removed by autoremove.
That is, by default one should expect it is fine to have desktop environment even if no other packages depend on it.

Comment: `gnome-session` is not installed during default installation. It is a dependency of `gnome-core`, though.

Comment: yup ... gnome-core on the other hand depends on evolution ... so the result is ... remove evolution and autoremove leads you to no gui at all

Comment: Yes, but that is because you installed gnome-core. Anyway, that lets me assume you removed Ubuntu desktop. If you did not remove that, many gnome components would remain in place because they are also dependencies of Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: I removed quite a lot of other packages, so can't be more specific than this. But you got it pinpointed in any case with gnome-session! :)